# Java program to count positive values in a Collection<Integer>

Tags: java

I am working on a program to count the positive values in an integer Collection and having an issue.  I am somewhat new to Java, and wondering if someone would be able to point out where I went wrong.

```
public class CountPositives {

/**
 * Returns the number of positive values in the given Collection.
 */
public static int countPositives(Collection<Integer> collection) {
 List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList(collection);
 int positive = 0; 
 Iterator<Integer> itr = copy.iterator();
 for (int i = 0; i < copy.size(); i++) {
         if (copy.get(i) > 0 ) {
             positive ++;
         }
 }
 return positive;     
 }
}
```

Comment: You are not using `Iterator<Integer> itr = copy.iterator();` so delete it.  Also show how you are using this code.

Comment: What is the issue that you're having? Is it a compile error? On what line? Or something else? Please be clear about what you expected to happen and what is happening instead.

Comment: Also why bother making the copy? You will not be making any changes to `collection`.

Comment: @MichaelL looks fine to me at first glance without compiling and running it myself, apart from the extra iterator and copy. What's going wrong?

Comment: Assuming it is not just a typo, there should not be space between `positive` and the increment operator, so should be: `positive++;`.

Comment: @KevinO:  That should be okay; the lexer is smart enough to know that this is the increment operator and not anything else.

Comment: why dont you consider using iterator for cllections like collection.iterator()

Comment: without seeing how this code is called, and the lack of a clear problem, any attempt to answer is pure speculation.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach:  This code would not be suitable on Code Review.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach:  https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/9874

Comment: @Makoto Thanks, but looks good to me? except maybe needing slightly more context?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach:  Honestly [I *personally* would strongly discourage anyone from posting a comment pointing another OP to Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362417/1079354) since that's caused significant amounts of confusion and strife.  Unless you *truly* know that this question would be a good fit there, it's better to let it lie here.

Comment: Fair, I did add some hedging language to soften it, and didn't recommend *this* specific question, or attempt to move, migrate, or close *this* question. So I'm a little on the fence.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me. (Although you have an `Iterator` you never use) However..

Maybe an easier way would be to do:

```
return (int) copy.stream().filter(e -> e > 0).count();
```

Which will filter out all the non positive numbers and then return the count of them. Also you can simply use the passed `Collection`:

```
public static int countPositive(Collection<Integer> collection) {
    return (int)collection.stream().filter(e -> e > 0).count();
}
```

Which will eliminate the copy `List` and the extra variables.

---

Note that [`count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) returns a `long`. If the size of `collection` might exceed the limit of an `int`, you will want to change the return type to `long` and not cast to an `int`.

Comment: You're right but given the context I would discourage the use of streams altogether here.  Streams are convenient but only if you understand them, and given the OP's declared experience, I worry that this would only serve to further confuse them.

Comment: @Makoto That is true. I was simply thinking of another way of approaching this problem for future readers

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `Iterator`.  [`Collection`s can automatically give you an iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator--), so there's no need to convert it to an `ArrayList` to get this.

```
Iterator<Integer> itr = collection.iterator();
```

Now you actually have to *use* it.  The `for` statement may look wonky to you as a beginner, but remember that a `for` statement starts with an optional initialization step, which can be omitted.

```
for(; itr.hasNext();) {
    Integer value = itr.next();
    // rest of your logic here
}
```

If you prefer, you can initialize the iterator in the `for` statement directly.

```
for(Iterator<Integer> itr = collection.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    Integer value = itr.next();
    // rest of your logic here
}
```

In spite of the wasteful copying, the code appears to be fine.  The critical part of the code is checking to see if there are positive values, and your code *does* accomplish that.  This is simply making it cleaner and less ceremonious.

Comment: It's a good code review, but it doesn't seem to address the (lack of) question in the question.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach:  I thought the question was, "Where did I go wrong?"  Do you see a different question?

Comment: I downvoted, immediately regretted it, and undid the vote. But I think my comment still stands.

Comment: There is also for-each syntax which would make things clearer still.  `for (int val: collection) { ...  }`.